# Map on on all scenes

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm making a prototype app heavily based on maps. I'm trying to replicate the way Apple Maps on iOS10 works, where there is a fullscreen map in the background and different scenes appears as cards on top and the content/markers in the map updates accordingly. The map will display markers and polylines, depending on the active scene, [similar to this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFWU3.jpg).

I have trouble figuring out how the app needs to be structured so that the map is present and "fixed" between all scenes, but also updates based on which card is being displayed.

Comment: Having a common persistent map in the background between different scenes is possible, however in the screenshot you posted that looks just like a single scene with the slide up implemented as a view. Therefore no need to do what you are asking for.